# Is it possible to have an optional output file in Snakemake?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm writing a snakemake rule that will handle performing fastq trimming on either single or paired end sequencing data. If the data is paired end there should be two output files, if single end, there should be one.

The rule I have written works so far, however, I don't have it that the second pair of the trimmed is an output file. This means that snakemake is not checking to see if that file exists. It will output, but it's not checking, is it possible to have an optional output?

```
    input:
    #get the value in the fast1 column
        fastq_file = lambda wildcards: return_fastq(wildcards.fastq_name,wildcards.unit,first_pair = True)
    output:
        out_fastqc = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fastpjson = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.json",
        fastphtml = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.html"
    params:
        fastp_parameters = return_parsed_extra_params(config['fastp_parameters']),
        fastq_file2 = lambda wildcards: return_fastq(wildcards.fastq_name,wildcards.unit,first_pair = False),
        out_fastqc2 = lambda wildcards: return_fastq2_name(wildcards.fastq_name,wildcards.unit),
        fastpjson = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.json",
        fastphtml = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.html"
    run:
        if config["end_type"] == "se":
            shell("{config[fastp_path]} -i {input.fastq_file} -o {output.out_fastqc} --json {output.fastpjson} --html {output.fastphtml} {params.fastp_parameters}")
        if config["end_type"] == "pe":
            shell("{config[fastp_path]} --in1 {input.fastq_file} --in2 {params.fastq_file2} --out1 {output.out_fastqc} --out2  {params.out_fastqc2} --json {output.fastpjson} --html {output.fastphtml} {params.fastp_parameters}")
```

The goal is that the out_fastqc2 would be includes as an optional output of the rule so that snakemake will check if it exists and appropiately give me an error if it doesn't.

If Snakemake doesn't allow optional outputs, I could just split into two rules, but that's not quite what I'd like.

Comment: It might be possible to construct the output outside of the rule, based on `config["end_type"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how does the `expand` function work. It is being called at the phase when Snakemake constructs the DAG of dependencies, and it uses the result of this function to construct the list of files for the `output` section.

I would suggest you to try the same: construct the list that would be either empty or not - depends on the condition.

This solution would work only if you know if you need the `out_fastqc2` in advance (however defining 2 rules with priorities does the same). If you get the information about the need of `out_fastqc2` only while running the rule, that is completely different case where you need checkpoints.

Below is the code that illustrates my approach: `out_fastqc2` becomes a string that describes the file (if the `end_type` is configured to `"pe"`), otherwise is becomes an empty list that doesn't change the list of outputs.

```
output:
    out_fastqc = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_trimmed.fastq.gz",
    out_fastqc2 = lambda wildcards: return_fastq2_name(wildcards.fastq_name,wildcards.unit) if config["end_type"] == "pe" else []
```

Comment: Can you explain in code what you actually mean by that? The language is not clear.

Comment: You cannot use functions in the output of snakemake.

Comment: @Anna-Leigh: I can ;). Anyway, looks like your question becomes ambiguous. You may specify variable number of files in the output section, based on the criteria that exists before you start the pipeline (for example based on the setting in config), but once the file is added to the output section you have to create it in your rule. That is logical as long as other rules could wait for that file and would be very surprised not to find it after the prerequisite rule has "successfully" finished.

Comment: @Anna-Leigh, to add to my previous comment: sometimes you don't know the number of files in advance (i.e. the it depends on the number of clusters that the rule produces). In this case you may use dynamic output (deprecated) or checkpoints. This would require Snakemake to rebuild the DAG based on the new information that arises after your rule finished.

Comment: @Anna-Leigh, and one more option you have is to build the optional file silently without even showing it in the output section. That would mean that you are free to either create the file or to miss it -- but no other rule would count on you creating this file. No dependency, just some files would be created along with other mandatory files that are being requested. Please clarify your question to get a more specific answer.

Comment: On Snakemake verision 5.4.4. using functions in the output results in syntax errors, however this is solved as:
`out_fastqc2 = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_2_trimmed.fastq.gz" if config["end_type"] == "pe" else []`

Answer (score 0):

Since the choice between paired-end and single-end seems to be fixed in the configuration, you may try to define the rule in two ways depending on the configuration:

```
if config["end_type"] == "se":
    rule do_fastp:
        input:
        #get the value in the fast1 column
            fastq_file = lambda wildcards: return_fastq(wildcards.fastq_name, wildcards.unit, first_pair = True)
        output:
            out_fastqc = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_trimmed.fastq.gz",
            fastpjson = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.json",
            fastphtml = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.html"
        params:
            fastp_parameters = return_parsed_extra_params(config['fastp_parameters']),
        shell:
            """
            {config[fastp_path]} -i {input.fastq_file} -o {output.out_fastqc} \\
                --json {output.fastpjson} --html {output.fastphtml} \\
                {params.fastp_parameters}
            """
if config["end_type"] == "pe":
    rule do_fastp:
        input:
        #get the value in the fast1 column
            fastq_file1 = lambda wildcards: return_fastq(wildcards.fastq_name, wildcards.unit, first_pair = True),
            fastq_file2 = lambda wildcards: return_fastq(wildcards.fastq_name, wildcards.unit, first_pair = False)
        output:
            out_fastqc1 = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_trimmed_1.fastq.gz",
            out_fastqc2 = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_trimmed_2.fastq.gz",
            fastpjson = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.json",
            fastphtml = config["fastp_trimmed_output_folder"] + "{unit}/{fastq_name}_fastp.html"
        params:
            fastp_parameters = return_parsed_extra_params(config['fastp_parameters']),
        shell:
            """
            {config[fastp_path]} \\
                --in1 {input.fastq_file1} --in2 {params.fastq_file2} \\
                --out1 {output.out_fastqc1} --out2 {output.out_fastqc2} \\
                --json {output.fastpjson} --html {output.fastphtml} \\
                {params.fastp_parameters}
            """
```

Comment: This also solves the problem, but I was hoping to have optional output without the need to have two rules, or in this case two versions of the same rule.